# How do I give command for killing gunicorn and running gunicorn in the same file of supervisord?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

I have a conf file:

```
[program:nxchill]
directory=/home/ubuntu/dev/nxchill
command=gunicorn /home/ubuntu/dev/nxchill/nxchill:app -b localhost:5000
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/nxchill/nxchill.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nxchill/nxchill.out.log
```

My objective is to first run the command:

```
sudo fuser -k 5000/tcp
```

which stops all the gunicorn processes and then the following command:

```
gunicorn /home/ubuntu/dev/nxchill/nxchill:app -b localhost:5000
```

So, when I made the `command` section in the conf file this:

```
command=sudo fuser -k 5000/tcp gunicorn /home/ubuntu/dev/nxchill/nxchill:app -b localhost:5000
```

Running the following command:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo service supervisor restart
sudo service supervisor restart
```

> nxchill                          FATAL     Exited too quickly (process
>   log may have details)

The logs are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
[2018-06-04 07:59:33 +0000] [1527] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1527)
[2018-06-04 07:59:33 +0000] [1523] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-06-04 07:59:33 +0000] [1523] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Now, the same error is there even if there is only single command existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to ignore the command `sudo fuser -k 5000/tcp` and directly run the `gunicorn` command.

The command should up the server so that the flask app is never down on system restart, etc.

Although, more and more ports will be used since the command to kill them is not being executed. This can be run by a cron job once in a day or in a week. Need not to worry about this command killing the flask app as it will be restored by supervisord.